# Function of door in front of nose landing gear bay on the 737

Tags: boeing-737, doors, nosewheel

I've been trying to model a 737 as accurately as possible, and I've seen this door in front of the nose landing gear bay a number of times.

[image]

I don't know what this door leads to, and I can't find any images that face it head-on so I could possibly read what the labels on the door says. Is anyone aware of what this door does? Thanks!

Comment: Which aircraft is that? Classic or NG? It seems this door is the [Lower nose compartment access door](https://b737mrg.net/mrg_download/B737MRG_doors.pdf) on both models anyway.

Answer (score 12):

It's called the "E&E Bay," for Electronics & Equipment. Inside are a bunch of black boxes for radios, radar, computers, and so forth. The crew doesn't go there; it's for maintenance. On the walk-around, the pilot checks that the door is closed & the handle is flush, but that's it.

There are two of them, one forward of the nosewheel, another aft of it. There is a door light labeled "EQUIP" that indicates when either door is open, just like a light for each of the forward & after entry and service doors, overwing exits, and so forth. Sometimes you'll see that light come on when maintenance is working on something electronic -- running a BITE test on some computer, replacing a component, or similar.

More info [here](http://www.b737.org.uk/eandebay.htm).

Comment: The photo in the OP is a 737 Classic, which has a different layout from the NG. The original photo is [here](https://www.flickr.com/photos/wbaiv/42300018395), which identifies it as a 737-300. A similar photo of the door in the same position on a Max-8 is [here](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/boeing-employees-checks-out-the-landing-gear-of-a-737-max-8-news-photo/931517932).

Comment: Can you share some diagram for the CL? [I've one which also shows the E&E bay on a -300](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhmO7.png) aft of the NWG doors.

Comment: @mins The video in the site that I linked in the answer has those, I believe.

Comment: @mins There are two bays. The door asked about in the OP accesses the forward one, while the door aft of the nose gear accesses the main bay. They're both referred to as "E&E bay" by crews; the maintenance techs care about which boxes are in which (obviously), but for crews, they're both doors to reach the same (sort of) thing. The video discusses both bays in this way, as well. (The Boeing graphic shows that there ***is*** the aft E&E bay, with the batteries in it, but doesn't exclude the forward bay as having other electronic things. Just not the batteries.)

Comment: The second door doesn't seem to be an access to the E&E bay: "*The purpose of the lower nose compartment access door is to permit access to the compartment below the flight compartment. Many flight control cables and brake accessories pass through this area.*"

Comment: @mins The FCOM calls the aft one "center electrical and electronic (E/E) equipment access door" and the forward one "equipment compartment access door" (both are connected to the EQUIP light on the flight deck). The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VbRE2tO4EA&t=2633s) Ralph linked also lists some electrical components in the forward one (PSEU, Fuel Quantity Processor Unit and WX Radar).

Comment: @Bianfable: Thanks, that clarifies everything: No opening in direction of the aft E&E bay, and also answers the OP request for the [decals on the door](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VbRE2tO4EA&t=44m35s).